# FCM heads up notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Tried all forums, but still can't make it work. Heads up notification is not working.

Tried max and high priority and vibrate full screen content, nothing is working. Using Android-Moto 5.1 version.

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution. In cordova-fcm plugin MyFireBaseMessagingService.java file onMessageReceived method - below line is commented(send notification).

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData());
```

Hope it helps someone. I uncommented this line and added the priority it works fine.